# list of subarrays of an array

Tags: arrays, f#

I am trying to implement a function `stride n a` where `n` is a stride length and `a` is an array. Given a call like `stride 2 [| "a"; "b"; "c"; "d" |]` it should return something like `[ [|"a"; "b"|]; [|"c"; "d" |] ]`. I am brand new to F# and don't know anything about using arrays in a functional language. I know what I've written is garbage, but it's a start:

```
let stride n (a : array 'a) =
    let rec r ind =
        if ind >= a.length()
        then
            []
        else 
            a[ind .. (ind + n - 1)]::r(ind + n)
    in
    r 0
```

(see also on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4w01vL)). This does not compile. I to added the `array 'a` type parameter because the compiler couldn't find the `length` method, but this type parameter does not appear to be allowed.

For context, I am trying to get groups of letters from a string, so I plan to call this like `stride 2 myString.ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is already an app for that - it's called [`Array.chunkBySize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.chunkbysize%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
> Array.chunkBySize 2 [|1;2;3;4;5;6;7|]
val it : int [] [] = [|[|1; 2|]; [|3; 4|]; [|5; 6|]; [|7|]|]
```

And there are similar functions in the `Seq` and `List` module, so if your goal is to work with strings, I would consider using the `Seq` variant, since `string` already implements the `seq` interface:

```
> Seq.chunkBySize 2 "abcdefg";;
val it : seq<char []> =
  seq [[|'a'; 'b'|]; [|'c'; 'd'|]; [|'e'; 'f'|]; [|'g'|]]
```

---

But if you're interested in education rather than GSD, then here it is:

The logic of the code is fine, except you have a few purely syntactic mistakes and one logical.

**First**, the type "array of a" is not denoted `array 'a`. In general the F# notation for generic types is either `T<'a>` or `'a T`, for example `list<int>` or `int list`. However, this doesn't work for arrays, because arrays are special. There is a type `System.Array`, but it's not generic, so you can't use it like that. Instead, the idea of an array is kind of baked into the CLR, so you have to use the special syntax, which is `'a[]`.

So: `a : 'a[]` instead of `a : array 'a`

**Second** while array does have a length property, it's capitalized (i.e. `Length`) and it's a property, not a method, so there shouldn't be parens after it.

So: `a.Length` instead of `a.length()`

However, that is not quite the F# way. Methods and properties are meh, functions are way better. The F# way would be to use the `Array.length` function.

So: `Array.length a` instead of `a.length()`

Bonus: if you do that, there is no need for the type annotation `: 'a[]`, because the compiler can now figure it out from the type of `Array.length`.

**Third**, indexing of arrays, lists, and everything else that has an index, needs a dot before the opening bracket.

So: `a.[ind .. (ind + n - 1)]` instead of `a[ind .. (ind + n - 1)]`

**Fourth**, the `in` is not necessary in F#. You can just omit it.

With the above modifications, your program will work.
But only on arrays whose length is a multiple of `n`. On all others you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This is because you also have...

**The logical mistake** is that while you're checking that `ind` is within the array bounds, you're not checking that `ind + n - 1` is as well. So you need a third case in your branch:

```
if ind >= Array.length a then
    []
elif ind + n - 1 >= Array.length a then
    a.[ind..] :: r (ind+n)
else
    a.[ind .. (ind+n-1)] :: r (ind+n)
```

Now this is ready for prime time.

Comment: Thanks! You've just taught me a lot about F#. After I made the changes, the function still throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException when I call `stride 2 [|"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g"|];;`. I tried replacing the newer case you added with `a.[ind..] :: []`, which looked more correct to me, but it still threw the exception. It's disappointing that mono doesn't even provide the line number that threw the exception in this case.

Comment: You have `>` instead of `>=` there.